# How to remember user choices in react router?

Tags: react-router

I am using react router to build a single page app.Now, everything is fine, except remembering the previous status. I mean: each time when user chooses one option in a select dom, then click a link component to jump to another route path; then, if this user clicks back button from browser to go back to the previous page, he can not see his previous choice, everything lost!

Answer (score 2):

The desired behavior you are talking about is about saving the State of the Component. Even though the router renders the desired Component, it does not save the State of that Component.
However, you can pass in a desired State via URL Parameters, but that doesn't like a solution for you due to what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Passing data in through the URL to achieve the state may sound like a good idea, but this won't work due to the URL having to be updated as the User selects different options, and this will trigger new rendering. This will happen because you are currently on that route.

```
//the route path can be defined like this:
localhost:123/#/userselection/:selectedid

When you navigate it will look something like this
localhost:123/#/userselection/1
localhost:123/#/userselection/2
localhost:123/#/userselection/3
etc.

//Now if you are on 
localhost:123/#/userselection/2

and the User changes to selectionid 3, you will have to trigger a render 
which is not usually desired behaviour
```

An idea may be to have some sort of ComponentStateService that is declared at a root level of your application. Use this Service to set and read desired state. So when the User selects something, have an Object with the Component Name, and its stateData.

```
export default class ComponentStateService{
    _stateData = {};

    constructor(defaultState = null){
        if (defaultState){
            this._stateData = defaultState;
        }        
    }

    getComponentStateData(componentName){
        if (this._stateData){
            return this._stateData[componentName];
        }

    }

    setComponentStateData(componentName, stateData){
        this._stateData[componentName] = stateData;
    }
}
```

Then initialize it something like this at a high level:

```
import ComponentStateService from './componentStateService';

var componentState = new ComponentStateService(//default state passed in here);
export default componentState;
```

Then to use it, import it to each component

```
import componentState from '../index';

// call this to set the state
componentState.setComponentStateData("component1", {});
// and retrieve state
let savedState = componentState.getComponentStateData("component1");
```

Then you retrieve or update as necessary. You can make use of the LifeCycle Hooks that react has in order to read and set the data before the Comopnent is Rendered. Also you will need to ensure that you are correctly updating the data for the state upon User changing their selection.

As you can see though, the major flaw is you cannot share your link and expect someone else to see what you see, since it will persist in a Users Browser Session.

You can create a base class that imports this, so you don't have to import it every time.

You can also dump the entire state to local storage so it persists beyond a session, and load it up on app start

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, buddy!But I want an automatic way, just like server rendered route acts.I know this way and I want to find an automatic way.But thanks for ur answer, i will mark this answer as useful!